# Angularfire2 - auth/argument-error when loading entities

Tags: angular, firebase, redux, angularfire2, ngrx

I'm writing an Angular 2 + ngrx application which uses Firebase as backend. When loading entities from firebase, and specifically when the resulting action is fired from the triggered NGRX effect, the following error is thrown.

```
{code: "auth/argument-error", message: "toJSON failed: First argument must be a valid string."}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y53Qc.png)

Specifically, I have a landing page which is shown after the user has signed in, which contains an overview of plans. On this landing page, the the currently signed-in user is retrieved from the `authState`, an its ID is used to launch the LoadEntities action.

```
this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if(user) {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadEntities('plan', ref => ref.where('owner', '==', user.uid)));
  } else {
    this.store.dispatch(new Navigate({path: ['/login', 'authenticate']}));
  }
});
```

I've configured an effect to be triggered when the `LoadEntities` action is launched on the Landing Page. A query is performed on the correct firebase collection, and the list of entities are returned. Finally, a `LoadEntitiesFinish` action is launched which contains the correct entities.

```
@Effect() loadEntities$ = this.actions$.ofType(ActionTypes.LOAD_ENTITIES)
.map((action: LoadEntities) => action.payload)
.mergeMap(payload => {
  let res: Observable<{}> = this.afs.collection<Entity>(payload.entityType, payload.query).snapshotChanges().map(angularFireAction => {

    let entities: Array<Entity> = angularFireAction.map(res => {
      let entity: Entity = res.payload.doc.data() as Entity;
      entity.id = res.payload.doc.id;

      return entity;
    });

    return {
      entityType: payload.entityType,
      entities: entities
    }
  }).catch((e) => {
    this.logger.error(AppEffects.name, 'Could not load entities', e);

    let res: Observable<any> = Observable.of(new LoadEntitiesFinish('test', null, 'Could not load entities', e));

    return res;
  });

  return res;
})
.map((response: any) => {
  let action: Action = null;

  if (response.entities != null) {
    action = new LoadEntitiesFinish(response.entityType, response.entities, null, null);
  } else {
    action = new LoadEntitiesFinish(response.entityType, null, 'Could not load entities');
  }

  return action;
})
.catch((e) => {
  this.logger.error(AppEffects.name, 'Could not load entities', e);

  let res: Observable<any> = Observable.of(new LoadEntitiesFinish('test', null, 'Could not load entities', e));

  return res;
});
```

The reducer correctly creates an updated state. However, when the state updates the above mentioned error is thrown.

```
case ActionTypes.LOAD_ENTITIES_FINISH:
  let LoadEntitiesFinishEntityType = action.payload.entityType;

  let LoadEntitiesFinisDelta = {}
  LoadEntitiesFinisDelta[LoadEntitiesFinishEntityType + 'List'] = action.payload.entities;

  return Object.assign({}, state, LoadEntitiesFinisDelta);
```

Does anyone has an idea why an authentication error is throw, after the user has already authenticated? What's the link with the query which has been launched?

Thanks!